# Probability problem with powers

Tags: probability

Given a set {1,2,...,100} two numbers *p* and *q* are being chosen randomly, but after I chose one number I can choose it again. Find next probabilities:

1. $p^q + q^p$ is an odd number
2. $p^qq^p$ is an even number

Since power of even number is always an even number and power of odd number is always an odd number(by power I mean the number is raised by natural number).
I have four options when picking p and q:

1. p is even and q is odd
2. p is odd and q is even
3. p is even and q is even
4. p is odd and q is odd

Solution for first probability, let's call it A:

I think that the sum will be odd number if p and q are from first and second option. Since the sum of two even numbers is even which is trivial and so as sum of two odd numbers it will be divisible by 2. Considering that I can choose any two numbers in $100^2$ ways. Also I have 50 even and 50 odd numbers so I can choose 1 odd and 1 even number in $\binom{50}{1}$$\binom{50}{1}$ or $50*50$ ways. So final probability for A is: $P(A)=\frac{\binom{50}{1}\binom{50}{1}}{100^2}$

Solution for second probability, let's call it B:

Considering what I wrote at the beginning $p^qq^p$ will be an even number if p and q are from first three options or to put it this way if one of these $p^q$ and $q^p$ is even or both of them are even. Since that I found the complement of B which is that $p^qq^p$ is an odd number(not sure about this). The probability of picking any two numbers is $100^2$ (since I can choose the same number again). In a given set I have 50 odd and 50 even numbers, since I need two odd numbers I can choose two of them in $\binom{50}{2}$ ways. So final probability of B is: $P(B)=1-\frac{\binom{50}{2}}{100^2}$

I really tried to explain in detail how I solved this. I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: First one is correct for the second one, just change it a bit as you can choose the same number twice

Comment: I see, so it will be $\binom{50}{1}$ times 2?

Comment: Yes, that's right and that completes your answer

Comment: pq is even if either is even - that is then the driver for whether or not (pq)^n is even - as you have correctly deduced.  What is the probability that neither is even?